# get all words exist in trie using recursion

Tags: c++, trie

I found a function which traverse all the trie and return a list contains all the words exist in my trie. My problem is I can't make this work for me, any help will appreciated.

```
class Node {
    public:
        Node();
        Node* ch[26];
        bool isEnd;
};

Node::Node() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
        ch[i] = NULL;
    isEnd = 0;
}


class Trie {
    public:
        Node* root;
        Trie() {root = new Node();}
        void insert(string word, Node* ptr);
        bool find(string word, Node* ptr);
        list<string> findWords(Node* root);
};

void Trie::insert(string word, Node* ptr) {
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < word.size(); i++) {
        if(ptr->ch[word[i]-'a'] == NULL)
            ptr->ch[word[i]-'a'] = new Node();
        ptr = ptr->ch[word[i]-'a'];
    }
    ptr->isEnd = 1;
}

list<string> Trie::findWords(Node* ptr) {
    list<string> result;

    if(ptr->isEnd)
        result.push_back("");

    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
        if(ptr->ch[i] != NULL) {
            ptr = ptr->ch[i];
            list<string> childResult = findWords(ptr);
            char letter = (char) (97 + i);
            for(string sufix : childResult)
                result.push_back("" + letter + sufix);
        }
    copy(result.begin(),result.end(),ostream_iterator<string> (cout," "));
    return result;
}
```

test main:

```
int main() {
    Trie T;
    string word;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cin >> word;
        insert(word, root);
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In what way does it not work? Is there a compile time error, run time error or logic error, and what specifically is the error (copy and paste if there's a message or output from the function)? Have you attempted to debug it at all?

Comment: no compile or runtime error
it gives me "the filer reading the filetn error reading the file  :: xsgetn error reading the file...." on the console
all operations are work fine insert & find except this function findWords

Comment: `result.push_back("" + letter + sufix);` is adding a pointer with a `char` and a `std::string`. That's not right.

Comment: so, what I can do for this?

Comment: I have edit my post for adding insert function and test main